# How to make WordPress orderby work with post_excerpt column?

Tags: order, excerpt, playlist

I can use WordPress in-built orderby to sort playlist by any column except `post_excerpt`

```
    echo wp_playlist_shortcode( array(
                        'ids' => '7,8,9',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => 'post_excerpt', 
    ));
```

WordPress Codex apparently states *'post_excerpt' is not a valid parameter for the 'orderby' parameter*, and nobody nowhere knows how to make `orderby` work with `post_excerpt`. How to bypass this limitation?

Comment: You might be able to use `'orderby' => {any valid parameter}` and then [`usort()`](https://php.net/usort) the resulting array of posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the `wp_playlist_shortcode` function at `\wp-includes\media.php` WP core file, by adding

```
    if ($atts['orderby']=='excerpt' || $atts['orderby']=='post_excerpt') {

        function cmp($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a["caption"], $b["caption"])*(-1);
        }

        usort($tracks, "cmp");
    }
```

before `$data['tracks'] = $tracks;` line.

Basically after all tracks are generated into the `$tracks` array and before this array is passed to the final array `$data`, I intercepted the code and checked if `orderby` parameter is set to `excerpt` or `post_excerpt`. If true did a `usort` to sort array descendingly by using `caption` as criteria. In playlist context, WordPress refers to `excerpt` as `caption`. If you need to be sorted ascendingly remove the `*(-1)` within the `cmp` function.

Thanks to the @Pat-J for suggesting `usort`.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem while trying to sort captions and descriptions of images. Captions are stored as post_excerpt and descriptions are stored as post_content.

What I ended up doing is using an existing ORDER BY parameter, then filter the [posts_request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_request/) to replace that parameter with post_excerpt or post_content as needed.

It's working, but I haven't tested this extensively.